# How do I pass parameters to a HandlerRoutine?

Tags: c, winapi, event-handling

I wanted to pass to my Ctrl signals handler an Event Object to notify the other threads of the event and behave accordingly to it.

In order to [handle a console Ctrl signal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) we need to define a `HandlerRoutine` and pass it to the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function. But from [the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) of the `HandlerRoutine` it seems like the only parameter we can pass to it is the type of Ctrl signal to handle.

How can I pass other parameters to my handler?

Comment: Question is a little broad. Generally, don't do complex code in your handler, just set a flag to indicate something happened, or exit. Your other code has to check a flag to see if something happened, and then do what it needs to do at that point.

Comment: The console host process (e.g. conhost.exe in Windows 7+) sends an LPC message to the Windows session server, csrss.exe, which in turn creates a remote thread in your process that starts at a private function (e.g. `CtrlRoutine` in kernelbase.dll in Windows 7+). The parameter for the thread is the control event; that's it. You could access static or instance data in your handler, but that has nothing to do with the console per se.

Comment: @jxh, except when handling `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` you don't want to return from the handler until you've cleaned up to exit gracefully. The console gives you 5 seconds for this before forcibly terminating your process.

Comment: You can access a global in another compilation unit. You just need to declare it (`extern`). Thread-safety has nothing to do with variables being global or not. Synchronization objects in the Windows API (like an Event object) are inherently thread-safe.

Comment: *"Singleton"* is the term invented by folks that despise globals, just so that they can feel better. No, a singleton doesn't make something that already is thread-safe any more thread-safe.

Comment: @IInspectable *Singleton* uses functions to interface with the object rather than the object directly. This allows for lazy allocation, lazy initialization, and initialization control (easier to avoid double initialization, for example). But yes, it is essentially a global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your handler is essentially stateless, if you want one thread to notify all the threads, it will require a global variable. One possibility is to use a single global to mark the received event.

```
received_events revents;

BOOL handler (DWORD e) {
    set_received_event(&revents, e);
    wait_if_needed_for_threads_to_handle_event(&revents, e);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then all the threads will have to check this global to see if something of interest happened:

```
extern received_events revents;

while (!done) {
    if (received_an_event(&revents)) {
        e = which_event(&revents);
        /* ... */
        mark_event_as_handled_maybe_exit_thread(&revents, e);
    }
    do_what_I_normally_do();
}
```

Comment: I guess since it's a thread safe object (I'll make the Event Object `extern`) there shouldn't be any problem with making it `extern` anyway